# What would be appropriate query in this scenario

Tags: mysql

Here is my scenario :

A user can post something on his profile, he can also share another user's post. I want to select in a query every post and share he has done (ordered using datetime). I just can't find the appropriate query with my basic MySQL skills. Help me find my way threw this! Cheers.

### Table post

```
id   user_id     content        datetime
1    100         Loremipsum1    2013-03-04 19:35:02 
2    200         Loremipsum2    2013-03-03 19:30:02 
3    200         Loremipsum3    2013-03-01 19:25:02
```

### Table share

```
id    user_id     target_id     post_id    datetime
1     100         200           2          2013-02-01 19:25:02
2     100         200           3          2013-02-01 19:24:02
3     200         100           1          2013-01-01 19:25:02
```

Let's say I would like to get every result for my user 100, the desired result would be

```
id   user_id     content        datetime
1    100         Loremipsum1    2013-03-04 19:35:02 
2    200         Loremipsum2    2013-03-03 19:30:02 
3    200         Loremipsum3    2013-03-01 19:25:02
```

because user 100 shared both post of user 200.

EDIT : Some people think that I'm trying to be lazy and to have someone else doing my work for me. So here is where I am at the moment in my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_stream
LEFT JOIN user_share
ON user_stream.user_id = user_share.user_id
WHERE user_id = 100
```

My problem here is that I need to select the content from my target_id not my user_id. But I have no idea of the target_id value. It could also be multiple value (if a user share multiple post).

Comment: So you don't want to learn but looking for someone just to do your work for free? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @zerkms Not at all! I really want to learn but I have no idea what to look for. Either give me pointer or anything constructive. I'm not trying to be lazy, but to do my work the best way I can. I worked already 3 hours on this problem before posting my question. Be more indulgent please.

Comment: Then look for `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @zerkms Thank you, at least it tells me I'm not too far from the answer.

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: @sgeddes in this scenario, let's say I would like to get all post/share from user 100, I would get everything from the table post because he shared the 2 post from user 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand what you're looking for, but to get a list of posts that a user has either created or shared, you can use `UNION` to combine the results.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, user_id, datetime, 'P' as type
    FROM post
    UNION 
    SELECT post_id, user_id, datetime, 'S' as type
    FROM share
) t
WHERE user_id = 100
ORDER BY datetime
```

The type tells you whether it were a post or a share.

---

Edit: Given your comments, then it looks like you just want the posts.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM post
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM post
    WHERE user_id = 100
    UNION 
    SELECT post_id
    FROM share
    WHERE user_id = 100
)
ORDER BY datetime
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, 

Unfortunatly it's not what I want. I have updated my question and added an example of the desired result. Apologies for not making my question easy to understand, english is not my native language.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve -- no worries -- just edited my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so much, I was so far away from the answer. You have made my day!

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve -- np, glad I could help!